# Avoid scaling up of image resources when the display size is changed in Settings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have designed a layout which has png images which is showing correctly when the Settings->Display Settings-> Display size is default. When the setting is changed to largest then the image is getting scaled up. I verified that in both the cases the xxxhdpi resource is picked up for the device which I tested, but the image width and height are getting increased when the display size is changed, how can I avoid this?

I am using constraint layout as shown below

Layout file

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/intro_device_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/intro_device_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/get_started"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_text"
    tools:text="Title" />
.....
```

When default display size selected : 
[image: Display size default]

When largest display size selected : 
[image: Display size largest]

Comment: "When the setting is changed to largest then the image is getting scaled up" -- that is what the user wants to happen, as that is the point of changing that setting.

Comment: Isn't that the point? So people with bad vision can make everything larger? If the xml is not enough to achieve what you want, maybe try it programmatically. Get the screen resolution and then change the layoutParameters in java.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CommonsWare, einUsername : I am ok with the larger text sizes, I am only trying to avoid the images scaling up at some places, For example I have a screen in which entire screen has an image with very small padding, I want to avoid scaling up in this case.

Comment: I can make the view scrollable though, but was thinking if I can avoid scaling of images at some places.

Comment: The _entire point_ of the feature is to simulate a smaller device and then scale it to fit the screen.  Please don't circumvent the feature, as you are harming the accessibility of your app by doing so.  If the layout is incorrect with the display size changed, then it will be incorrect on a smaller screen, and you should fix *that* rather than trying to fight this feature.

Comment: @RyanMentley : I was mainly trying to fix this for the splash screen background and some other places where entire screen contains an image, the image used for splash screen is getting stretched and not looking good when display size is set to largest, it looks fine with the smaller screen devices. Other places of the app accepts the accessibility settings and scales up/down as per setting.

Comment: "I was mainly trying to fix this for the splash screen background and some other places where entire screen contains an image" -- then get rid of those images.